# Keeping imported modules out of python package namespaces

Tags: python

I've noticed sometimes if you call `dir()` on a package/module, you'll see other modules in the namespace that were imported as part of the implementation and aren't meant for you to use. For instance, if I install the fish package from PyPI and import it, I see `fish.sys`, which just refers to the built-in `sys` module.

My question is whether that's sane and what to do about it if it's not.

I don't think the `__all__` variable is too relevant, since that *only* affects the behavior of `from X import *`. The options I see are:

- structure your packages better, and at least push the namespace clutter down into submodules
- use `import X as _X` in your package to distinguish implementation details from your package API
- import things from inside your functions (*blegh*)

Comment: I don't get it. If it's not meant for you to use, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is whether that's sane

It's sane. Doing `import fish` adds just one name to your namespace, that is not "namespace clutter". It's pretty much the big idea behind modules, grouping many things under one name!

When you want to know what a module does, look at the **documentation** or call `help`, don't do `dir`.

All names in Python are stored in dictonaries. This means that no matter how many names you see, looking up one of them takes constant time. So there is no speed drawback of any kind either.

Comment: I do look at documentation and help when available, but `dir` is convenient if, e.g., I keep forgetting some long function name.

Comment: And yeah, I wasn't really concerned about speed or anything, just tidy package organization.